# using jquery FileTree to access a different server?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am currently attempting to access files on a different server using [file tree.](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/) I was wondering if this was possible? It's using PHP script to pull the data. I am able to get to the root of my own server, but I can't seem to direct link into another server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating your own custom PHP connector and set it to use FTP rather than scandir. It should not be too difficult to do - just create a new version of the /connectors/jqueryFileTree.php file. Below is a VERY basic example of connecting to an FTP server using PHP to get you going.

```
$conn = ftp_connect("ftp.hostname.com");
$login = ftp_login($conn, "username", "password");
$n = ftp_nlist($conn, "dir");
foreach($n as $value){
        echo $value, "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that's an idea I didn't think about... might try it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're running into security restrictions fromt he [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)?  Can you use JSONP to get your data?

Comment: That's what I think I am running into. The only thing that doesn't make sense is that I am using PHP to pull the data from the server and I don't know if that same policy applys.

Comment: If the PHP script is not on the same web server as your HTML file which runs your jquery script, then same origin policy will block you and you need to use JSONP.  If the PHP script that fetches the data is on the same server as your HTML file, something else is wrong.  If you hit the PHP script directly (instead of from jquery) does it return the right data?

Comment: The HTML file and the PHP script are on the same server but the file I am attempting to reach is on a different server.